# saving boolean values in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, boolean

I am kind of new to this. Whilst reading the sqlite documentation, it said that we boolean values cannot be in sqlite. I am really lost here so any help is appreciated. I am using a checkbox and I want to now how I can save that in sqlite

Comment: With this comment I want to refer to the people who just down vote without any explanation. Some people are just new and want to learn. If you have time to press that button, just try to spend few seconds more and give some proper explanation, except of or along with down voting, because this is the place where people just ask with the hope to get some clear answers, if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class.

you can convert a boolean value to int and store in TINYINT(1) column type

```
data = booleanValue ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1.1 Boolean Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

You should have read it to the end. [See here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)